# CakePHP: Aco and Aro Model customization

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

**Scenario:**

1. I have been successful in implementing and using CakePHP Authorization module. I have created the `acos`, `aros` and `acos_aros` tables and set them up to leverage permissions.
2. My application has multiple datasources and the active datasource is determined by parameters assigned on the user record (after login)
3. I would like the `Aco` and `Aro` Model objects to leverage a datasource depending on the user's login credentials.

**What I have done thus far**

I tried creating my own Aco and Aro model objects and tried to override the `construct` method where I would set the right datasource

**Result:**

I get a lot of error messages stating that the system cannot find Aco or Aro and in some cases that I cannot redeclare these objects.

Has anyone tried this before? Help is greatly appreciated!!! Am using CakePHP 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the AclBehavior, and override the beforeSave to add your logic. (in your case, you would change the datasource in the beforeSave function). Then attach your CustomAclBehavior to your model, rather than the default AclBehavior.
This way, you can avoid creating a new Aco and Aro model.